# Is it safe to use DbCommand.CreateParameter?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

I want to ask you if I use this method ([DbCommand.CreateParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.createparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2)) in C# to transmit my parameters value to my stored procedures, then I am safe againt SQL-Injection? Or what can I do otherwise against SQL-Injection?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What makes you think it might be 'unsafe'?   And in what way?

Comment: Parameters in SQL Server are always safe from SQL injection, barring dynamic SQL on the server side.

Comment: @DanGuzman Parameters in SQL Server are _almost_ always safe from SQL injection, I saw code sending user input within the parameters sent to an`EXEC` command. Given that, using parameters is always the way to go when talking about sql injection

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. Are there any official sources, where that is written? It is not that I don't believe you, but I have to prove this information for my company?

So that means if I don't use dynamically SQL Code, I am safe from SQL-Injection with the parameters.

Comment: @GianPaolo, in expanded on that in my answer. Stored procedures alone don't prevent injection but parameters do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server parameter objects are always safe from SQL injection, barring dynamic SQL on the server side using the parameter values. This is because parameterized queries executed as an [RPC call over the TDS protocol](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34484/difference-between-sql-batch-statement-and-rpc). The parameter values are passed separately from the statement in native format and not parsed as SQL by the server. Since the parameter values are not parsed as SQL language elements, the values cannot be executed and there is no SQL injection vulnerability.

It is also best to specify command type stored procedure as an additional layer of safety when calling stored procedures. This ensures only the stored procedure name is specified as the command text and parameters passed separately. Otherwise, a developer could unwittingly build a command text string in an unsafe way (i.e. containing both parameter markers and literal values from an untrusted source or even not use parameters at all).